# Unable to install apache2 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I'm facing the below errors when installing apache2 on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.18) but 2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1~ubuntu14.
          04.2 is to be installed
Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.18) but 2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1~ubuntu14.04.2 is 
          to be installed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the previous package getting in the way. Remove it completely. Then try

```
sudo aptitude install
```

Comment: that should work! if it doesn't Check whether there are any configuration files that have not been removed.
using   whereis apache2

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove using

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2*
```

and then install using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```